# For fourier series g(x), prove that the fourier series for the integral G(x) can be found by term-by-term integration of g(x)

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I want to prove that if I have a fourier series of the form $g(x) = a_0/2 + {\sum_i}^\infty a_icos(ix) + b_isin(ix) $, the fourier series of G(x) $-x*a_0/2$ can be found by simply integrating g(x) term by term.

I've found the term by term integration of g(x), but I'm confused by how I can know that this is in fact the fourier series for $G(x) -x*a_0/2$.

Comment: IBP: $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}G(x)\cos(kx)\,dx = \left. G(x)\frac{1}{k}\sin(kx)\right|_{0}^{2\pi}-\frac{1}{k}\int_{0}^{2\pi}g(x)\sin(kx)\,dx.$$

Comment: You have the coefficients of the Fourier (cosine) series of $G(x)$ in the LHS and the coefficients of the Fourier (sine) series of $g(x)$ in the RHS.